# Adjust positioning of label inside rectangle

Tags: ios, objective-c

Please take a look at screenshot:[image]

It appears that label position is center of rectangle that contain that label. How to make label to be attached at bottom/top?

Comment: Autolayout ?? Autoresizing ?? What have you used????

Comment: you mean you want set text at bottom of label instead of center right?

Comment: Why are you using two labels to do a work of one? What happen if your user use font with increased size? And also it's not good for accessibility...

Comment: @SandeepBhandari i use auto layout. I did make 2 labels because i need exacly two.

Comment: What you can do is set minimum font size to something less and label will automatically adjust and dont forget to add constraint from top and bottom @EvgeniyKleban